# AJAX sending a base64 image to an external server

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jsonp, base64

I'm trying to send a base64 image generated on one server and sent to a PHP file on another.  So far all I'm getting cross origin errors on the client side and the server with the PHP file doesn't seem to receiving anything.

Here's the code:

Server 1 JS :

```
function shareDesign() {
    $('#twitter').on('click', function() {
        //console.log('?image='+encodeURIComponent(canvasExport)+'&designName=test')
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://mysite.com/share_page.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                image : canvasExport ,
                designName:'test'
            } ,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Server 2 PHP:

```
$image = $_POST['image'];
$designName = $_POST['designName'];

$sHTML_Header = "<html><head><title>SHare design test</title></head><body>"; 
$sHTML_Content = '<div id="test"><img src="'.$image.'"/> This design is called : '.$designName.'</div>' ; 
$sHTML_Footer =  "</body></html>"; 

echo "parseResponse({'status' :'success'})";
```

Addition:

I need this to work on mobile, is this possible?  Also I do not have any server control on the JS server it's on adobe business catalyst.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript

Comment: you have to add a headers to server2 php :
`header('Content-type: text/html');header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 1st_server_domain')`

Comment: I need this to work on mobile, is it possible to send the base64 without posting?

Comment: When you fix the cross-origin errors, you will have another problem. In order to display image by it's base64 encoded content, you should prefix with data: <img src="data:'.$image.'"/>

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'm going to have to work in some i-frame magic.

Comment: @Darhazer That is included in the canvasExport var.

Comment: same problem with the i-frame. any other ideas?